# Does the series $\frac{\cos(\pi n)}{n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Does the series $\left\{{\cos(\pi\cdot n)\over n}\right\}$ converge?

I think it does, but can't find a series convergence test that applies to it.

I can't compare it to the series $\left\{{1\over n}\right\}$, and I can't use the integral test. What do I do?

Comment: Maybe write a few terms of the sequence $\cos(\pi n)$ to get an idea of the pattern.

Comment: $cos(πn)$ actual equals $(-1)^n$ try writing out a few terms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The criteria you mention apply only for series with positive terms, which is not the case here.
$$\sum_n\frac{\cos n\pi}n=\sum_n\frac{(-1)^n}n$$
This is the *alternating harmonic series*, it it is proved to be convergent using *Leibniz criterion* for alternating series:

> If $f(n)$ decreases to $0$, the alternating series $\displaystyle\sum_n (-1)^nf(n)$ converges.

Comment: You mean $\sum_n (-1)^n f(n)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael that was some other user, not Bernard, who somehow had the edit approved.

Answer (score 4):

Hint : $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^n$ and $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$